# Converting html code to lightning component doesnt give same output

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, html, popup

I am trying a popup and have got it something like this: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GGWMU0XY0R43 and I am now trying the exact functionality using lightning component. But when the same html code is included in lightning, it is not giving the exact output(compared to the html code). The lightning code is as below:

Component

```
<aura:component >
    <lightning:button aura:id="myBtn" label="Help" class="open-button" onclick="{!c.openForm}"/>
    <h2>Popup Form</h2>
    <p>Click on the button at the bottom of this page to open the login form.</p>
    <p>Note that the button and the form is fixed - they will always be positioned to the bottom of the browser window.</p>
    <div class="form-popup" id="myForm" style="position: fixed;width:300px;overflow-y: scroll;margin-left:80%;margin-top:1%;height:600px;display:none;border:2px solid red;">
        <form class="form-container">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            
            <label for="email"><b>Some text</b></label>
                       
            <label for="psw"><b>Some Text</b></label>            
            
            <lightning:button name="test" label="Login" class="btn"/>
            <lightning:button label="Close"  class="btn cancel" onclick="{!c.closeForm}"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

CSS

```
/* Button used to open the contact form - fixed at the bottom of the page */
.THIS .open-button {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: 4px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: fixed;
  right: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  text-align:right;
}

/* The popup form - hidden by default */
.THIS .form-popup {
  display:none;
  position: fixed;
  top:2px;
  bottom: 40;
  height:510px;
  right: 2px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 30px solid #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 9;
}

/* Add styles to the form container */
.THIS .form-container {
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Controller:

```
({
    openForm : function(component, event, helper) {
        document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
    },
    closeForm : function(component, event, helper) {
        document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
    }    
})
```

The html code that I tried is below(which is also available [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GGWMU0XY0R43)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

/* Button used to open the contact form - fixed at the bottom of the page */
.open-button {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: 4px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: fixed;
  right: 2px;
  width: 120px;
}

/* The popup form - hidden by default */
.form-popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top:2px;
  bottom: 40;
  height:510px;
  right: 2px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 9;
  width:300px;
}

/* Add styles to the form container */
.form-container {
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Full-width input fields 
.form-container input[type=text], .form-container input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  border: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}*/

/* Set a style for the submit/login button 
.form-container .btn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}*/

/* Add a red background color to the cancel button 
.form-container .cancel {
  background-color: red;
}*/

/* Add some hover effects to buttons 
.form-container .btn:hover, .open-button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}*/
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button id="myBtn" class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">Open Form</button>
<h2>Popup Form</h2>
<p>Click on the button at the bottom of this page to open the login form.</p>
<p>Note that the button and the form is fixed - they will always be positioned to the bottom of the browser window.</p>



<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
  <form class="form-container">
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <label for="email"><b>Some Text</b></label>
    Some Text
    <br/>
    Some Text
    <br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can you please let me know where it is going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Create the style classes for display:none and block. Then use addClass, removeClass and toggleClass instead of document.getElementById("myForm"). Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Shailesh for your response but if you check the output of HTML code and lightning component, visually they are not same. I am trying to achieve the HTML code output using lightning component but something seems going wrong somewhere in lightning code which is what I am trying to correct to make it's output look like exactly that of output of HTML code..

Comment: You're not going to get "the exact same HTML output", not in Aura, LWC, React, or any other template-framework system. What matters is behavior. What behavior are you seeing? What are you expecting?